# How do i call external javascript file in cshtml file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Below is my Javascript file.

Copy.js

```
function CopyYourSheet() {

    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1992ry0dpIjel_TQuB-W6fb2Nd7uST69AX_jY/edit#");
    ifrm.style.width = "10000px";
    ifrm.style.height = "2000px";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
    }
```

Below is the CSHTML File

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>                    
        <button id="CopyYourSheet" onclick="CopyYourSheet()">Get your details</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The right way to include it is through bundling the Copy.js into your bundle.

under App_Start folder open BundleConfig

Then add

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myjs").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/copy.js"));
```

then include it in your Home view like this

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myjs")
```

If you do not have an App_Start folder or you do not prefer to bundle in an MVC project, then include the script inside of the `<head>` tags of your _Layout partial view. Adding it right above the closing `</head>` tag would be best.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/copy.js"></script>
```

Be sure the path to the file is correct. You may need to remove the /Scripts/ folder in the src path, if the js file resides in your main project tree. The ~ should remain at the start of the path to make it flexible when the code is ran from different environments.

Comment: Thanks.  But i am not able locate this App_start folder. I am using latest version. Kindly help me to get this.

Comment: I have edited the answer for an alternative solution to include the script

Comment: Please accept the answer if this resolved your issue. Thanks